# Why does a function (not object of function) have (prototype) property?

Tags: javascript

While reading [this](https://github.com/rupeshmi/CodeSprint/blob/dev/JavaScript/Part2/Prototypes.md) article about `prototype, I saw the following picture:

[image]

I'm confused because I thought that only objects have properties so `person1` (created using the `new` operator) should have `__proto__` property, but why does `Humen` **function** have it also?

---

As you can see, my terminology in JS still weak so it affects my searches capabilities to look for answers to simple questions. Fill free to forward me to a relevant article which answers this particular question.

Comment: Yes, only objects have prototypes. But in JS, everything is an object (seriously, even _arrays_ are!)

Comment: Yes, objects too have properties. Types are objects.

Comment: I want to ask - Why types are objects in JS? But I may ask the wrong question. Any guidance?

Comment: Javascript has: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, Symbol, String, and Object. If you don't find what you are looking for in that list (e.g. Array or Function), it's an object.

Comment: @JaromandaX the callable form of `Boolean`, `Number`, `Symbol`, and `String` all return primitives though, I think that was the point being attempted. And `Symbol` isn't even constructable, for that matter, which is funny since it looks like a constructor by all other means.